# Iframe alternative Java Script To Display External Website

Tags: iframe, blogger

First of all please don't mind if this is not the right section to post my query here, and move it to whatever right section is.

I'm almost new to any language, actually I'm a blogger and usually Google whatever I need, but this time I can't find the exact script I needed therefore I decided to post my query here.

I want to display center part of the external website (say Google.com logo) in my blogger post or page with no scroll bar and border color, before this I used `iframe` which works perfectly but I don't want to use it anymore due to its some limitations, the biggest restriction using `iframe` is that  it's not search engine friendly.

So please help me by posting alternate code or script to achieve my goal.

Comment: Signature is removed, Please refer the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the content to be search engine friendly, the best way is to retrieve it server side and render it with the rest of the page. I don't know what scripting languages you have at your disposal but any will do (i.e. PHP).There are plenty of examples here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Having said that, you must know that duplicating content contravenes Google webmaster guidelines and could hurt your site's rankings.

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66359